# OpenAI Gym save_video getting memory errors

Tags: openai-gym, openai-api

I'm running the `LunarLander-v2` gym environment and have successfully trained a policy using PPO. I saw the [gym API](https://www.gymlibrary.dev/api/utils/) that there is a function to save videos to a file. I need to do this as I am running my code on a server and there isn't a GUI. I've looked into the source code of `save_video` as well and notice that it saves videos in a "cubic" fashion. Videos of episode number [0, 1, 4, 27, 64, etc.] will be saved. I followed the example in the API but excluded `step_starting_index` as I don't think I need that. My code is below:

```
frames = env.render()
save_video(
    frames,
    "videos",
    fps=240,
    episode_index=n
)
```

Episode 0 and 1 successfully gets saved, but after that (Episode 2, 3 or 4), the Python process gets `Killed`, which suggests a memory error. If I comment out `save_video` and let it run, the evaluations up to Episode 10 and beyond all succeed. This suggests that there seems to be a problem with `save_video` and I can't identify it.